# Jenkins doesn't fully resolve variables values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile where I want to declare some variables to later use in other sections. I know about Jenkins use the Groovy syntax rules for variable expansion but I expected some variable values where fully resolved. Instead I found that they just resolved in one level. Code inlcuded below shows what I want: Trying to use $PATHTOFILES variable to link data downloaded/generated in previous stages for a Docker container. Instead the variable is just resolved as `pwd`.

I tried several options seeking to expand the values that I need, so far unsuccessfully.

```
  agent none
  environment {
     ...
     PATHTOFILES = "`pwd`"
     ...
  }
  ...
  stage('Unit'){
     agent {
        docker {
           image "${DOCKERIMAGEURI}"
           args '-v $PATHTOFILES:$CONTAINER_DATA_PATH'
        }
     }
  }

Logs show that a value '-v `pwd`:/some/valid/path' is used as argument, leading to an error. Any ideas?
```

Comment: That volume mapping is already done by the Jenkins Pipeline Docker Agent automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong to get current workspace of job. One of below 3 methods should work:

```
1) use shell cmd: pwd and pipeline step: sh() together 
PATHTOFILES = sh(script: 'pwd', returnStdout:true).trim()

2) use pipeline step: pwd()
PATHTOFILES = pwd()

3) use environment variable: WORKSPACE
PATHTOFILES = env.WORKSPACE
```